# TV show with a sand pit in the middle of a forest that accelerate aging

Tags: story-identification, tv

I want to say it was outer limits or something along that genre.
It was probably in the early 90's, it was live action in color.
It may have been one of those types of shows that had multiple stories in one episode.

All I remember was there were 3 people probably in there early 20's, I think it was 2 men and one woman.

They were in a secluded forest and decided to split up and go exploring when the girl came across a sand pit in the middle of a nice green forest.

Later on when the girl never returned, the guys found her in the middle of the sand pit and she aged like 70+ years and warned the guys to stay out of the sand. 
After they got help and notified the authorities, they show a helicopter flying over the sand pit to drop concrete over it to cover it up.

That's about all I remember!

Comment: Do you think you could tell us if this was live-action or cartoon? when did you see this? color or black and white?

Comment: The Jumanji episode [An Old Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Jumanji_episodes) is quite similar, except it was a whirlpool instead of a sand pit and there wasn't any concrete at the end.

Comment: How did this possibly get downvoted?

Comment: It reminds me of the Futurama episode when the gang gets youthenized and need to find the fountain of aging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Psi Factor: Chronicles of the Paranormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psi_Factor%3a_Chronicles_of_the_Paranormal)

Specifically, the scenario you're describing is from Season 1, Episode 8. The episode was called "Transient, The/Two Lost Old Men". Here's an excerpt from the episode's [IMDB synopsis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0668508/synopsis):

> Rangers find an old man, Doug Kilmartin, stumbling out of the woods.
>   His ID says that he is 21 years old. Doyle, Hendricks, Donner, Axon
>   and team investigate and find Doug's colleague who is also 50 years
>   older than his ID. Kilmartin insists there is a third person, a woman,
>   and that the ageing happened after finding a dead zone with no growth,
>   just sand.

Comment: Wow, That is it! You are Awesome!